# Excess Roth IRA Contribution - How to Capture Earned Interest No 1099 r?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, excess-contribution

I contributed over the limit to my Roth IRA in 2018. I realized this and have withdrawn the excess contribution plus earnings in 2019, and have not yet filed my 2018 tax return. My Financial advisor cannot provide a 1099 r form retro to 2018, but the earnings are taxable for that year. How do I capture the earned income with no 1099 r for my 2018 tax return?

Similarly I have already made a contribution to my Roth IRA in 2019 which I will need to withdraw as I will be over the limit. How can I clarify on the 2019 1099r that 1.) there was excess contribution for 2018 with earnings already taxed and 2.) there was excess for 2019? The form only allows for one code but these are two different codes.